# Correlation matrix like DataFrame in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have Polars dataframe

```
data = {
    "col1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "col2": [[-0.06066, 0.072485, 0.548874, 0.158507],
             [-0.536674, 0.10478, 0.926022, -0.083722],
             [-0.21311, -0.030623, 0.300583, 0.261814],
             [-0.308025, 0.006694, 0.176335, 0.533835]],
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to calculate cosine similarity for each combination of column `col1`

The desired output should be the following:

```
┌─────────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1_col2       ┆ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    ┆ d    │
│ ---             ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str             ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a               ┆ 1.0  ┆ 0.86 ┆ 0.83 ┆ 0.54 │
│ b               ┆ 0.86 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 0.75 ┆ 0.41 │
│ c               ┆ 0.83 ┆ 0.75 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 0.89 │
│ d               ┆ 0.54 ┆ 0.41 ┆ 0.89 ┆ 1.0  │
└─────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Where each value represents cosine similarity between respective column values.

I tried to use `pivot` method

```
df.pivot(values="col2", index="col1", columns="col1", aggregate_function=cosine_similary)
```

However I'm getting the following error

```
'function' object has no attribute '_pyexpr'
```

I'm using following cosine similarity function

```
from numpy.linalg import norm

cosine_similarity = lambda a,b: (a @ b.T) / (norm(a)*norm(b))
```

However, I can use any implementation of it

Comment: Can you show the code for `cosine_similarity`? `aggregate_function=` takes a Polars expression not a python function object.

Comment: I've edited the post @jqurious

Comment: I don't understand your setup. All the rows of col2 are the same. On your expected output of (a,b) you have 0.67. What do `a` and `b` need to be to get that result from ` (a @ b.T) / (norm(a)*norm(b))`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor this is just an example. The idea is that I have input and I need to apply cosine similarity to the input to get the output format. Note that the output is either lower triangular or upper triangular matrix. Exact values does not matter. If I would have solution it will work on exact values as well

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Ah my fault. Actually, let me fix that problem. Sorry about that

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I've fixed the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cross join + filter to get the pairs. (i.e. [`combinations_with_replacements(..., r=2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement))

And use expressions for the similarity calculation:

```py
x = pl.col("col2").flatten()
y = pl.col("col2_right").flatten()

row = pl.first().cum_count()

cosine_similarity = (
   x.dot(y) / (x.pow(2).sum().sqrt() * y.pow(2).sum().sqrt())
).over(row)

(df.join(df, how = "cross")
   .filter(pl.col("col1") <= pl.col("col1_right"))
   .select(
      col    = "col1",
      other  = "col1_right",
      cosine = cosine_similarity
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ col ┆ other ┆ cosine   │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ a   ┆ a     ┆ 1.0      │
│ a   ┆ b     ┆ 0.856754 │
│ a   ┆ c     ┆ 0.827877 │
│ a   ┆ d     ┆ 0.540282 │
│ b   ┆ b     ┆ 1.0      │
│ b   ┆ c     ┆ 0.752199 │
│ b   ┆ d     ┆ 0.411564 │
│ c   ┆ c     ┆ 1.0      │
│ c   ┆ d     ┆ 0.889009 │
│ d   ┆ d     ┆ 1.0      │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

You can then `.pivot` if desired.

Answer (score 2):

## One way

(first thing I thought of, second way is better)

#### Reshape initial df

You need the values that you want to compare to be column oriented, not rowwise.

```
df = (
    df.select('col2').transpose().pipe(lambda ab: (
        ab.explode(ab.columns)
        .rename({
        oldcol:newname 
        for oldcol, newname in zip(ab.columns,df['col1'])
        })
    ))
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ a        ┆ b         ┆ c         ┆ d         │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ -0.06066 ┆ -0.536674 ┆ -0.21311  ┆ -0.308025 │
│ 0.072485 ┆ 0.10478   ┆ -0.030623 ┆ 0.006694  │
│ 0.548874 ┆ 0.926022  ┆ 0.300583  ┆ 0.176335  │
│ 0.158507 ┆ -0.083722 ┆ 0.261814  ┆ 0.533835  │
└──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

#### Define UDF and generate Expressions for pairs

```
def cosine_similarity(structin):
    a=structin.struct[0].to_numpy()
    b=structin.struct[1].to_numpy()
    return pl.Series([(a @ b.T) / (norm(a)*norm(b))])


col_mixes={}
for i, col1 in enumerate(df.columns):
    for col2 in df.columns[i:]:
        new_name= f"{col1}___{col2}"
        col_mixes[new_name] = (
            pl.struct(col1, pl.col(col2).alias(f'_{col2}'))
            # col2 needs to be aliased for when col1==col2
            .map_batches(cosine_similarity)
            )
```

This first redefines your function to accept a polars Struct Series and then it just carries forward what you were doing anyway and returns a Series. The for loop is creating a dict of expressions, it's not doing any calculations yet. That comes next. What's happening is that for each possible combination of columns it creates the expression to calc the similarity between the two.

#### Reshape results to square matrix format

```
(
    df.select(**col_mixes).melt()
    ## perform all the expressions and melt to rowwise
    .with_columns(pl.col('variable').str.split('___').list.to_struct(fields=['left','right']))
    .unnest('variable')
    ## split ___ deliminated value to left and right variables
    .with_columns(
        left=pl.concat_list('left','right'),
        right=pl.concat_list('right','left')
        )
    .explode('left','right')
    ## double up rows for diagonal symmetry  
    .pivot('value','left','right','first')
    ## pivot to final form
    .sort('left')
    .pipe(lambda newdf: (
        newdf.select('left',*newdf['left'])
    ))
    ## sort row and column wise
)
shape: (4, 5)
┌──────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ left ┆ a        ┆ b        ┆ c        ┆ d        │
│ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1.0      ┆ 0.856754 ┆ 0.827877 ┆ 0.540282 │
│ b    ┆ 0.856754 ┆ 1.0      ┆ 0.752199 ┆ 0.411564 │
│ c    ┆ 0.827877 ┆ 0.752199 ┆ 1.0      ┆ 0.889009 │
│ d    ┆ 0.540282 ┆ 0.411564 ┆ 0.889009 ┆ 1.0      │
└──────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

## Second way

```
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:])], "(n),(n)->(n)")
def similarity(u, v, res):
    uv = 0
    uu = 0
    vv = 0
    for i in range(u.shape[0]):
        uv += u[i] * v[i]
        uu += u[i] * u[i]
        vv += v[i] * v[i]
    res[0] = 1
    if uu != 0 and vv != 0:
        res[0] = uv / np.sqrt(uu * vv)
        
def cos_sim(left_col, right_col):
    return (
        similarity(left_col.explode(),
                   right_col.explode()).first()
    )
```

This creates the `similarity` ufunc which is compiled with numba as a ufunc and `cos_sim` is an expression based wrapper that will help use the function in polars.

Then instead of doing the transposes, hacking column names, or making the df have every combo at once, this uses a for loop with a shift. Internal to the loop, it uses `lazy` so that when it's collected, it is run in parallel.

```
pl.concat([
(
    df.lazy().with_columns(right_val=pl.col('col2').shift(i), right=pl.col('col1').shift(i))
    .filter(pl.col('right_val').is_not_null())
    .with_columns(sim=cos_sim(pl.col('col2'), pl.col('right_val')).over('col1','right'))
) for i in range(df.shape[0])
]).collect().pivot('sim','col1','right','first')

shape: (4, 5)
┌──────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ a        ┆ b        ┆ c        ┆ d    │
│ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ a    ┆ 1.0      ┆ null     ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ b    ┆ 0.856754 ┆ 1.0      ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ c    ┆ 0.827877 ┆ 0.752199 ┆ 1.0      ┆ null │
│ d    ┆ 0.540282 ┆ 0.411564 ┆ 0.889009 ┆ 1.0  │
└──────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

If you want the symmetric look then grab the earlier lines with the `concat_list` and corresponding `explode` and put those before the `pivot`.

It was arbitrary that the first approach used a normal `map_batches` and the second uses the ufunc, that aspect could be switched between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I found some simple solution. However, one needs to convert Polars to Pandas. **This does not answer my question directly**, but for newcomers or anyone interested how to do the task in Pandas here it is

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

data = {
    "col1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "col2": [
        [-0.06066, 0.072485, 0.548874, 0.158507],
        [-0.536674, 0.10478, 0.926022, -0.083722],
        [-0.21311, -0.030623, 0.300583, 0.261814],
        [-0.308025, 0.006694, 0.176335, 0.533835],
    ],
}


df = pl.DataFrame(data)

pd_df = df.to_pandas() # Copy Polars to Pandas


result = np.round(cosine_similarity(np.array(pd_df["col2"].tolist()),
                                    np.array(pd_df["col2"].tolist())), 2)

final_df = pd.DataFrame(data=result, index=df["col1"], columns=df["col1"])
```

And `final_df` is the following:

```
col1     a     b     c     d
col1                        
a     1.00  0.86  0.83  0.54
b     0.86  1.00  0.75  0.41
c     0.83  0.75  1.00  0.89
d     0.54  0.41  0.89  1.00
```

Comment: You can remove `.to_pandas` and do `pl.from_numpy(np.round(cosine_similarity(df["col2"].to_list(), ...)))` - but it's still having to convert to lists, so not ideal.